# How to build custom PropertySource for binding to @ConfigurationProperties

Tags: java, spring-boot

We're creating a new `PropertySource` that uses a database as it's repository.  The idea is that we can update property values at runtime.

At the same time, we'd like to use `@ConfigurationProperties` to so we can include validation as well as use the application-{profile} naming conventions.

However, it appears that values of `@ConfigurationProperties` are only loaded from "applicationConfig: [path/to/config]" `PropertySource`'s.  For example, the following test:

```
private final String OVERRIDEN_VALUE = "overriden value";

@Before
public void before() {

    LOGGER.debug("Property sources are: "); 
    for(Iterator<?> it = env.getPropertySources().iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
        PropertySource<?> propertySource = (PropertySource<?>) it.next();
        LOGGER.debug(propertySource.getName());
    }

    EnvironmentTestUtils.addEnvironment("integrationTest", env, "some.prefix.overridable-property=" + OVERRIDEN_VALUE);

}

@Test
public void testOverridingDefaultProperties() {

    LOGGER.debug("MutablePropertySources value: {}", env.getProperty("some.prefix.overridable-property"));
    LOGGER.debug("@ConfigurationProperties value: {}", testProperties.getOverridableProperty());

    Assert.assertEquals(OVERRIDEN_VALUE, testProperties.getOverridableProperty());

}
```

Produces this output:

```
Property sources are: 
    systemProperties
    systemEnvironment
    random
    integrationTest
    applicationConfig: [classpath:/path/to/my/application.yml]

MutablePropertySources value: overriden value
@ConfigurationProperties value: default value
```

For more context, I originally asked this question on Spring Boot's Github [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/3511).

Comment: It looks like you [answered yourself](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/3511#issuecomment-121967537), right?

Comment: Yeah I think I'm good.  I'm going to shoot for using the Cloud Config context.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the Spring Boot folks.  Pointed me to Spring Cloud Context

http://projects.spring.io/spring-cloud/spring-cloud.html#customizing-bootstrap-property-sources

Looks like this will do the trick.

**Update:**

Since we already had the additional database-backed `PropertySource` written we really only needed to refresh the `@ConfigurationProperties` at runtime.  At the same time we didn't want to refresh all `@ConfigurationProperties`.  To accomplish the refresh we did the following:

1. Created an annotation called `@ReloadableProperties`
2. Created the following utility bean which utilizes Spring Boot's `ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor`

```
/**
 * 
 * Helper bean to reload {@code @ConfigurationProperties}
 * if the {@code @ConfigurationProperties} bean is annotated 
 * with {@code @ReloadableProperties}.
 * 
 * @author Jonathan Martin
 * @since 2.0.0
 * 
 * @see ReloadableProperties
 * @see ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor
 *
 */
public class ConfigurationPropertiesReloader {

    private final ApplicationContext context;

    private final ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor processor;

    @Autowired
    public ConfigurationPropertiesReloader(ApplicationContext context,  ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor processor) {
        this.context = context;
        this.processor = processor;
    }

    /**
     * Reload all {@code @ConfigurationProperties}
     * annotated with {@code @ReloadableProperties}.
     */
    public void reload() {
        Map beans = context.getBeansWithAnnotation(ReloadableProperties.class);
        for (Map.Entry entry : beans.entrySet()) {

            String beanName = entry.getKey();
            Object bean = entry.getValue();

            ConfigurationProperties annotation = AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(bean.getClass(), ConfigurationProperties.class);

            // Only reload the bean if it's an @ConfigurationProperties
            // Can't check for instance of ConfigurationPropertiesHolder 
            // because it uses package scope.
            if (annotation != null) {
                processor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(bean, beanName);
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Now if I inject the utility bean into my test and invoke reload, the test passes.